# Xamarin Studio Won't Allow Click for Next button

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin-studio

I have the SDK manager for Android installed and updated on my PC currently running a Windows OS And i also have Xamarin Studio downloaded and installed for Windows.
Challenge is, i try as much as possible to create a new `"Helloworld"` project and the Next button has bluntly refused. What could be the issue really? I am Totally new to this

Comment: It may be helpful for you to include a screenshot of the screen in question.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that could come thru at this Moment was installing a lower version of Xamarin. I installed http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Windows/XamarinStudio-5.9.5.9-0.msi as the community version and it didnt give issues installing and no grey out buttons in this case, Thought I'd post the answer here